# Category exclusion in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working on this Wordpress website - http://adsclip.com/

I've built a country selector using this code (in it's simplest form)

```
<select name="countries" id="countries" style="width:180px;" onchange="return change_action(this.value);">
<option value='us' id="us">United States</option>
<option value='gb' id="gb">United Kingdom</option>
</select>
```

The posts throughout the Wordpress are grouped into country categories, my aim to exclude categories throughout the website when a specific country is selected.

If possible I'd like to just exclude them from the homepage.

Is there a plugin, or some code that can help me achieve this?

Comment: What categories you want to exclude and where is the related code of it?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude/include categories globally by passing the selected country's slug as a query parameter in `pre_get_posts` or `parse_query` actions.

Example with `pre_get_posts`:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_query_by_country' );

function filter_query_by_country( $query ) {

    // ... get the wanted country's slug here someway ...

    $query -> set( 'country', $slug );
}
```

In the above hooked function `'country'` is the taxonomy name and `$slug` is the country term's slug. It sets a query variable to solely search content marked with the certain `country` set (similar to the ordinary `category_name` query variable). You can target various queries with `$query -> is_main_query`, `is_category()` and similar conditionals.

If you have a JavaScript solution for implementing a query variable on each page when a certain country is selected this example should work. Google for `query_vars` filter and `add_rewrite_endpoint` core function to learn how to implement customized GET parameters in WordPress.

Additionally you could save the selected country to a session variable to keep the selection saved for the user (I presume you're creating a language switcher here?).